# Authorization in .Net Framework 4.8 returns Unauthorized using OpenIdentity4

Tags: rest, identityserver4, .net-4.8

I'm trying to use Authorization in .Net Framework 4.8, but making a get request returns Unauthorized using OpenIdentity4
I have to use Framework and not Core!

This is my Startup.cs:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var authority = "https://localhost:5001";

            var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
               authority + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
               new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
               new HttpDocumentRetriever());
            var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            System.Console.WriteLine(discoveryDocument.AuthorizationEndpoint);
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
               new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
               {
                   
                   AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                   TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                   {
                       ValidateAudience = false,
                       
                       
                   }
               }) ;
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "RestAPI",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc;
            
            
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

OpenIdentity4 is running on https://localhost:5001

It's Startup:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IWebHostEnvironment Environment { get; }

        public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            Environment = environment;
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddDeveloperSigningCredential() 
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients);
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy => {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim("RestAPI", "APIRest");
                });
            });
            
        }


        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            if (Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            // uncomment if you want to add MVC
            //app.UseStaticFiles();
            //app.UseRouting();
            
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseRouting();
            // uncomment, if you want to add MVC
            app.UseAuthorization();
            //app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            //{
            //    endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            //});
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers()
                .RequireAuthorization("ApiScope");
            });

        }
    }
}
```

It's probably a stupid mistake, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: I would change the ordering so  app.UseRouting(); is before app.UseIdentityServer();

Comment: Did you try to look into logs for errors? I believe either server or client should tell something useful in case of exception. Set Loglevel=Debug to see more details